# PHP - Search array recursively for key and subkey, return key['subkey] on success

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

So I wrote a function that searches two levels deep into an array for a key and subkey pair.  Basically it is looking for `key['subkey']` and if it finds it, returns `key['subkey']`.

What I am looking for is a way to do this in a manner that is truly recursive and searches as many levels deep as needed until it either reaches the end of the array and is forced to return false, or finds the value and returns it.

I am completely newbish at PHP, and I have googled for hours with no result.  Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

This is the function:

```
function searchArray($array, $key, $subkey) {
    foreach ($array as $item){
        if (is_array($item) && isset($item[$key]) && isset($item[$key][$subkey])){
            return $item[$key][$subkey];
        } else {
            foreach ($item as $subitem){
                if (is_array($subitem) && isset($subitem[$key]) && isset($subitem[$key][$subkey])){
                    return $subitem[$key][$subkey]; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Array:

```
"locales" => array(
    "America" => array(
        "locations" => array(
            "us" => array(
                "title" => "United States",
                "lang" => "en_US",
            ),
            "gl" => array(
            )
        )
    ),
    "Europe" => array(
        "locations" => array(
            "at" => array(
                "title" => "&Ouml;sterreich",
                "lang" => "de_DE",
            ),
            "fr" => array(
                "title" => "France",
                "lang" => "fr_FR",
            ),
            "de" => array(
                "title" => "Deutschland",
                "lang" => "de_DE",
            ),
            "it" => array(
                "title" => "Italy",
                "lang" => "it_IT",
            ),
            "uk" => array(
                "title" => "United Kingdom",
                "lang" => "en_GB",
            )
        )   
    ),
    "Africa" => array(
        "locations" => array(
            "za" => array(
                "title" => "S&uuml;dafrika",
                "lang" => "en_ZA",
            )
        )
    ),
    "Asia &amp; Pacific" => array(
        "locations" => array(
            "au" => array(
                "title" => "Australia",
                "lang" => "en_AU",
            ),
            "cn" => array(
                "title" => "中国",
                "lang" => "zh_CN",
            ),
            "hk" => array(
                "title" => "香港",
                "lang" => "zh_CN",
            ),
            "jp" => array(
                "title" => "日本",
                "lang" => "jp_JP",
            ),
            "kr" => array(
                "title" => "한국",
                "lang" => "ko_KR",
            )
        )
    )
)
```

calling `searchArray($siteOptions['locales'], 'us', 'lang')` should return `'en_US'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function walk($array, $key, $option) {
    if( !is_array( $array)) {
        return false;
    }
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if($k == $key && is_array($v) && isset($v[$option])){
            return $v[$option];
        }
        $data = walk($v, $key, $option);
        if($data != false){
            return $data;        
        }
    }

    return false;
}

echo walk($array, 'jp', 'lang');
```

Comment: I had to wrap the foreach loop in  `if (is_array($array){}`, other than that, perfection! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

```
function searchArray($arr, $key, $subkey) {
    $it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    $found = false;
    foreach($it as $k => $v) {
        if ($k == $key && !$found) $found = true;
        elseif ($k == $subkey && $found) return $v;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Tried this out, but $k never returns the value I am looking for, so I can't search for it.

Comment: @StephenRios  I wrote the original version before you posted the array sample. This one is short and sweet and does the trick. I'm too late for the checkmark, but I thought I'd leave it here for future generations. LOL

Comment: This version also works and saves a few lines of code. Nice!  Now if only I understood how they worked lol.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `array_walk_recursive()`: https://www.php.net/function.array-walk-recursive

It won't do exactly what you want by default; you'll have to write a bit of code to check subkeys and whatnot.

Comment: beat me to it by 10 seconds ;-)

Comment: I originally was trying to use array_walk_recursive, but it does not return values correctly when there are indexed arrays mixed in with the associative arrays.

Comment: can you post a small sample array? it sounds like what you want to do can be done by calling `array_walk_recursive()` recursively (i.e. inside the callable function you pass to `array_walk_recursive()`.

Comment: Sample array added.  right now I am calling my function like this: `searchArray($siteOptions['locales'], 'us', 'lang')`, which will look for `"us"` (or whatever value I feed it), make sure it's an array that contains a value with a key of `'lang'`, and if it does, returns `'lang'`.